# How to connect already running ganache-cli from brownie

Tags: brownie

I have a local ganache running at port X. I want to deploy my contract to this already running local ganache rather than spinning a new one. In other words, once the local ganache is started, I want other code in my machine to connect and deploy the contract.

I have tried running `brownie run scripts/deploy.py` without a network option, but it automatically creates a new ganache-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Just start ganache-cli / Ganache UI prior to the `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`, brownie is smart enought to "see" it